# Vector functions and motion along a curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

> A particle moves along the curve $x=\ln y$ with a constant speed of $4$ units per second. Find the normal scalar component of acceleration as a function of $x$.

Honestly, what I don't understand is how to make it into a vector function. I know how to proceed if I had it all in terms of $t$. I would derive the acceleration and use the formula for the normal scalar. Essentially what I have is the positions of the particle, how do I take it and make $\vec r(t)$?  Is this how?
$$\vec{r}(t)= x \hat i + \ln y \hat j$$

Comment: honestly what I don't understand is how to make it into a vector function. I know how to proceed if I had it all in terms of t. I would derive the acceleration and use the formula for the normal scalar. Essentially what I have is the positions of the particle, how do I take it and make r(t)= xi + lnyj is that how?

Comment: Thanks!  Knowing that, your question is much more specific and answerable.  (I'll write up an answer now...)

Comment: Hey, anorton is there anyway you could help me out a little more?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to to convert between a curve that is given explicitly is to let $x$ or $y$ be $t$, and then continue from there.  So, if we have the equation:
$$x=\ln y$$
This is the same as:
$$y = e^x$$

Now, we can re-write this as a system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
x=t\\
y=e^t
\end{cases}$$
This system can be turned into a vector-valued-function:
$$\vec{r} = (t, e^t)$$

Or, in $\hat i\hat j\hat k$ form:
$$\vec{r} = t\hat{i}+e^t\hat j$$

If I've skipped over a step somewhere, let me know with a comment below.

Comment: That's consider a parametric correct? Thank you so much, I've been killing myself over how to make it into a position vector. THANK YOU! I just have one question. The next step is to get v(t) and then get a(t) by deriving, I'm not entirely sure as to what to do with the speed. I know the speed is the llvll. Is that to calculate the normal scalar?

Comment: @Jose Yes, that is a parametric equation.  To find the normal scalar component of acceleration, I suggest this paper: http://www.math.vt.edu/people/alattime/1224/1224-recitation10.pdf It shows the method to an easy(ish) way to find the normal scalar component of acceleration.

Comment: I see. Well the equation that I learned to find the normal scalar component involves using the cross product of the vector for velocity and acceleration and dividing by the llvll which in this case is 4 units per second. Is that more or less in the right track?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I'm not sure if it's okay to bother so much but I just want to make sure. For the normal scalar I get e^t k / 4. I'm not entirely sure how to make it back to a function of x since it's now a vector k.

Comment: Your normal **scalar** component shouldn't have a $\hat k$ in it...  But, as far as converting back from $t$ to $x$: since $x=t$, we can just substitute back in.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry I meant to say that when I did the cross product I had a k but after getting the magnitude of the cross product and divided by 4 I got x= 4ln y. Again it looks correct but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't see how you can let $x$ be $t$. This seems incompatible with $v=4$. Since speed is constant, the normal component is the entire magnitude of the acceleration.

Comment: @dfeuer Speed is constant, yes, but the velocity is not.  I don't see how this is inconsistent at the moment.  I could be wrong, but I'm not seeing it right now--could you expound upon that?

Comment: The velocity is not constant, but it is determined by the slope of the curve. There is no freedom. $(dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$ is the slope of the curve, and $(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2$ must be $4^2$. Together, these determine both components of the velocity.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm still not seeing why that is a problem with making $x=t$.  That's what I did all through my physics/analytic geometry course, and it got me the right answers.  I guess I'll have to "sleep on it," and hope I figure it out by morning.

Comment: @anorton, I'm not going to say that it won't work, because I haven't worked through it, but you certainly haven't justified it.